# Delete the actual Object in a map - Javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

Basically i'm trying to work with a map in javascript. And when i'm  using a button, i want to delete the actual object used by the map (not only a element, literally all the things on this part of map). And when it's done, i'm reading the next etc...
Right now i have a map, i'm reading all my objects, but i don't know how can i delete the actual Object Used.

```
Show() {
  return this.state.loads.map((data) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Text key={data} style={styles.inputText}>{data.service}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity  style={styles.buttonDel} onPress={() => this.delete(data.id)}>
        <Icon reverse name='delete' type='material' color='#54a9eb' size='20'/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  })
}
```

If anyone have an idea, thanks.

Comment: `loads.splice(objectIndex, 1)` ... you could get currentIndex from secondParam of `map`

Answer (score 0):

`splice` in javascript removes your target element ... but you need to create a new **copy** of your `loads` array (in a new location in memory) ... cause `react` does only shallow comparison to determine when to re-render

```
  deleteItem = (index) => {
    const { loads  } = this.state;
    /** Important to make `setState` force refresh */
    let newLoads = loads.slice();
    newLoads = newLoads.splice(index, 1); /* Remove one element at index*/
    this.setState({ loads: newLoads });
  };

  return this.state.loads.map((data, index) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Text key={data} style={styles.inputText}>{data.service}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity  style={styles.buttonDel} onPress={() => this.deleteItem(indx)}>
        <Icon reverse name='delete' type='material' color='#54a9eb' size='20'/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
```

Comment: This looks like a sensible bit of code, but it would be great if you could explain how it works, and how that addresses OP's problem!